# Actionbarsherlock Up Affordance Icon without standard logo/icon

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using Actionbarsherlock and would like to display the up affordance icon without my app's logo or icon display to the right of it.

I have tried the following.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The result of this is that my up affordance icon does not display either.

If I leave off

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

then my up affordance icon displays, but it displays my app's icon as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a transparent png as I was unable to find a way to actually disable the icon programatically.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the icon to `null`.  `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(null)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that had no affect.

Comment: What if you set your icon to a transparent png?

Comment: @Parth, I hadn't gotten an answer after a few days so I tried that very thing and was coming back her to post that it works! Thanks for the suggestion.  I created a transparent png 1 pixel wide and set that as the icon.